# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class EditText

Tags: android, xml

' android.view.InflateException : Binary XML file line # 54 : Error inflating class EditText ' is generated when the login screen is completed and run due to the project. 
How do I solve this?

Below are the error contents and source.

> error :  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         Process: com.example.min.project, PID: 2930
>                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.min.project/com.example.min.project.LoginActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error
>   inflating class EditText
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class EditText
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                             at com.example.min.project.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:24)
>                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.example.min.project:drawable/round_background" (7f060068)  is not
>   a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060068 a=-1
>   r=0x7f060068}
>                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
>                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
>                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
>                             at android.view.View.(View.java:3737)
>                             at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:637)
>                             at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:65)
>                             at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:61)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:64)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:191)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:113)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                             at com.example.min.project.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:24) 
>                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
>                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

LoginActivity source :

```
package com.example.min.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlertDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        final EditText idText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idText);
        final EditText passwordText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String id = idText.getText().toString();
                String pw = passwordText.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseLister = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if(success){
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                dialog = builder.setMessage("success login")
                                        .setPositiveButton("확인", null)
                                        .create();
                                dialog.show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NoticeActivity.class);
                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                            else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                dialog = builder.setMessage("Please check your ID and password.")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(id, pw, responseLister);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }
        });

    }
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Login.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="227dp"
            android:background="@color/colorLogin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sunmoon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="scholl"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="attend system"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/idText"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:hint="Id"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#808080"
                android:textColorHint="#808080" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordText"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
                android:hint="Pw"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#808080"
                android:textColorHint="#808080" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a background like below `round_background.xml`. Find by `ctrl + shift + n` and type this xml name.

Move that to `res>drawable`.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.
I have a question.
Shouldn't it overlap padding in ' login.xml ' and padding in ' round_background.xml '?

Comment: You should not use padding in `round_background.xml`. Just use this in your EditText.

Comment: ' < Padding
Android : left = " 45 px "
Android : top = " 15 px "
Android : right = " 45 px "
Android : bottom = " 15 px " / "
Isn't it possible to use padding like this?

Comment: Because you can use that background in other views also, so you should use paddingTop, paddingBottom in EditText instead of background drawable.

Comment: The solution is to remove padding of ' EditText ' instead of ' round_background ' for Box rounding. Thank you very much.
May I ask you a question?

Comment: If you can show your required Editext view, i can tell you best approach. So please post your UI here in question. and yes you can ask.